# How to test logic in ComponenWillMount using Enzyme/Jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I am beginner in react unit testing with enzyme/jest,
I want to test my logic inside componentWillMount method.
I want to test based on my context object whether redirect happens or not based on my business logic

```
class ActivateSF extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.className = 'ActivateSF.js'
    this.state = {
      messages: null,
     }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <SDPActivateInterstitialUI
        context={this.props.context}
        messages={this.state.messages}
      />
    );
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    let context = this.props.context

    if(!context.userInfo){      
      return this.callIdentify(context)
    }

    let externalLP = ExternalLandingPageUtil.getExternalLandingPageUrl(context);
if (externalLP) {
      window.location.replace(`${externalLP}`);
      return;
    }

    if (context.userInfo)
    {
      console.log("user identified prior to activation flow")

        if (UserInfoUtil.isSubsribedUser(context))
        {
           window.location = '/ac'
        }

        else
        {
            this.callPaymentProcess(context)
        }
    }

  }
```

Comment: can you show what you've tried so far?

Answer (score -1):

You can try beforeEach to mount and in your test you call `.unmount` and perform your test on it.

```
beforeEach(() => {
     const myComponent= mount(<MyComponent myprop1={...} />);
});


describe('<MyComponent/>', () => {    
  it('actually unmounts', () => {
     ...
     ...
     myComponent.unmount();
    ... Do unmount tests here
  });
});
```

Example straight from the enzyme docs: https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/unmount.html

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import sinon from 'sinon';

const spy = sinon.spy();

class Foo extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.componentWillUnmount = spy;
  }

  render() {
    const { id } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className={id}>
        {id}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
Foo.propTypes = {
  id: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};
const wrapper = shallow(<Foo id="foo" />);
expect(spy).to.have.property('callCount', 0);
wrapper.unmount();
expect(spy).to.have.property('callCount', 1);
```